# Assigning fishnet attributes by row instead of by column with ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, attribute-table, cursor, vector-grid

I created a fishnet grid and assigned numeric attributes 1-16 to a new field using the `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor` function. It however assigned the attributes north to south (see image).

[image: fishnet attributes]

How can I change it so that the attributes are assigned from top-left to right i.e row by row as opposed to column by column? I know this could be achieved by the grid index tool but I used the fishnet tool because it allows me to draw the grid starting at the northwest corner drawing to the east which the grid index tool cannot achieve.

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("myfish1",("OID","switch")) as cursor:
for row in cursor:
    row[1]=row[0]
    cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: The Sort tool has a Spatial sort option once you add the Shape field. UL - sorting starts from the upper left corner.

Comment: If you include the geometry in the cursor column list, you could use the X and Y of its centroid to locate the desired value. Populating a fishnet is so trivial, I'd just create in manually, but there is at least one question here which assigns IDs via a PostgreSQL SQL expression.

Comment: @klewis Wow that worked!!! Thank you so much. I'll accept your answer if you post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [suggested](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254631/assigning-fishnet-attributes-by-row-instead-of-by-column-with-arcpy/312445#comment401521_254631) by user klewis, you can perform a spatial [Sort](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/sort.htm) by using the `Shape` field* (before updating the column `switch` with `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor`, if needed). *Requires a Desktop Advanced license.

Set the `spatial_sort_method` parameter equal `UL` (upper left). It will reorder rows based on position of rectangular cells in the fishnet starting from top, and going from left to right through horizontally aligned features. For example:

```
arcpy.Sort_management("myfish1", "myfish1_sorted", sort_field = [["Shape", "ASCENDING"]], spatial_sort_method = "UL")
```

Take a look at illustrations from [this](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/how-sort-works.htm) article to have a better idea how the sort method works.